# Sequelize findAndCountAll with literal count and having clause

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When using sequelize findAndCountAll with a literal that counts the number of rows i get an error

`Unknown column 'banCount' in 'having clause'`

Here is my code

```
const users = await db.User.findAndCountAll({
        attributes: {
            include: [
                [
                    fn(`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM \`Bans\` WHERE \`Bans\`.\`UserId\` = \`User\`.\`id\` AND \`Bans\`.\`active\` = true)`),
                    'banCount',
                ],
            ],
        },
        having: {
            banCount: 0,
        },
    });
```

I'm wondering if anybody would know how to use findAndCountAll with having and a count literal

Answer (score 0):

If you used the `underscored` option in the Sequelize model definition, you must use `ban_count` instead of `banCount` in the literal query (you may have the same issue for other fields).